# How to find the centroid of an arc slice when the slice does not start at angle 0?

Tags: javascript, geometry, pie-chart

I'm trying to find the centroid of each slice in a pie chart. Assuming the center of the circle is the origin, how do I calculate the x and y coordinates of the centroid of each slice?

I have the radius, start angle, and end angle of each slice.

I know how to calculate the centroid of a slice when that slice's starting angle is 0; that's answered [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034520/how-to-find-the-middle-point-of-an-arc-slice) But this assumes you have the angle alpha of the slice, starting at 0 (which JavaScript assumes is the place normally thought of as pi/2). I want the coordinates of, for example, the centroid of the red slice in this photo:

[image: pie chart].

Let's say the angle alpha of the red slice is 1 radian (for simplicity, startAngle = 6 and endAngle = 5, this isn't exact but close to the actual angles in the photo) and the radius of the chart is 400px. Using the formula, xbar = (2/3)(r/a)sin(a) = (2/3)(400/1)(.84147) = 224.39226px which would be ~225px to the *right* of the origin, nowhere near the actual x coordinate of the centroid because the formula assumes the start angle of the slice is 0.

Also, the starting point being the coordinates of pi/2 and not 0 may contribute to the problem? I'm not sure.

How do I find the actual x coordinate of the centroid?

Comment: Take the point you found and rotate it around the circle's center by the starting angle

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Oop, found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410809/how-to-calculate-rotation-in-2d-in-javascript), I'll figure out and post my complete answer once I get it. Thank you, @BenWest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ben West's comment, I was able to determine the answer. You have to rotate the point around the center point of the circle `startAngle` radians.

Also note if using JavaScript that the circle starts at pi/2 and rotates clockwise instead of counterclockwise like the sin and cos functions, so you have to account for that.

Code:

```
computeCentroid(slice, chart) {
    const startAngle = slice.startAngle - (Math.PI / 2), endAngle = slice.endAngle - (Math.PI / 2);
    const alpha = endAngle - startAngle;
    const radius = chart.radius;

    // get coordinates of centroid if startAngle = 0
    const xbar = (2 / 3) * (radius / alpha) * Math.sin(alpha);
    const ybar = (-2 / 3) * (radius / alpha) * (Math.cos(alpha) - 1);

    // rotate coordinates about (0, 0) by startAngle
    const xCoord = xbar * Math.cos(startAngle) - ybar * Math.sin(startAngle);
    const yCoord = ybar * Math.cos(startAngle) + xbar * Math.sin(startAngle);

    return [xCoord, yCoord];
}
```